# last_insert:_id always returns 0

Tags: php, pdo, last-insert-id

In PHP the MySQL method (like the PDO::lastInertID()) always returns 0 whereas MySQL returns in properly.

I tried try-catch, object initialization, but didn't work.

```
abstract class Database
{

    private static $host = "localhost";
    private static $dbname = "loquor";
    private static $charset = "utf8";
    private static $dbType = "mysql";
    private static $dbUsername = "root";
    private static $dbPassword = "";

    private static function connect ()
    {   
        $dsn = self::$dbType . ":host=" . self::$host . ";dbname=" . self::$dbname . ";charset=" . self::$charset;
        $connex = new PDO( $dsn, self::$dbUsername, self::$dbPassword );
        $connex->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        return $connex;
    }

    public static function query ($query, $params = [], $lastInsertID = false)
    {
        if(!$lastInsertID)
        {
            $statement = self::connect()->prepare($query);
            $statement->setFetchMode(\PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
            $statement->execute( $params );
        }
        else
        {
            if (explode ( " ", $query )[0] === "INSERT")
            {
                $statement = self::connect()->query($query);
                $x = self::connect()->query("SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() AS L")->fetch()['L'];
                echo $x; //always 0
            }
        }
        if (explode (" ", $query )[0] === "SELECT")
            return $statement;
    }
}

Database::query("INSERT INTO test(name) VALUES ('test_name') ", [], true));
```

Returns 0.

Comment: Because you create a new connection for each `connect()`. Make it a static property of the class instead.

Comment: Declare a static variable `$connex`, then check if its defined or not - if it is, use it - otherwise define it as the PDO object.

Comment: "The ID that was generated is maintained in the server on a per-connection basis. This means that the value returned by the function to a given client is the first AUTO_INCREMENT value generated for most recent statement affecting an AUTO_INCREMENT column by that client." -- dev.mysql.com